# Laravel 5.4 Class 'App\Http\Controllers\Admin\Auth\Auth' not found

Tags: php, laravel

I've got this error while logging into the admin section. We have used the sample project from this url - https://github.com/jayminpanchal/laravel-multiauth-demo.

This is the complete error got::

```
Whoops, looks like something went wrong.

1/1
FatalErrorException in LoginController.php line 52:
Class 'App\Http\Controllers\Admin\Auth\Auth' not found
in LoginController.php line 52
```

Comment: I think you are missing a \ in your controller before Auth Try to use \Auth::user for example instead of Auth::user

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 9):

[This issue](https://github.com/jayminpanchal/laravel-multiauth-demo/issues/4) was posted on the github repo you reference.

The solution posted by github user [aliwesome](https://github.com/aliwesome) seemed to be that you must use Auth Facade in Admin\Auth\LoginController

add this line :use `Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;`

Comment: thanks dude.,..... i'm such an idiot... didn;t checked the project full details.... u r really a life saver..